# Angular - shared service vs standalone components

Tags: javascript, angular

Why does increasing variable **Z** number in shared service does not increase that number in other standalone components which use that variable **Z** from shared service ?

This is the issue:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-15-starter-project-mn2aey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're telling Angular to create a new Instance of the service for each component you have.

You can solve it by using the `singleton` pattern as following:

#### Remove the import of the service from the components:

```
 providers: [ShareService] // <-- remove this line
```

#### Add a global reference to the `ShareService` in the `Main.ts` file:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [ShareService],
});
```

By doing this, you have just one instance of the service running and the result is what you're looking for:

[image]

Comment: what is the difference between your proposal and adding @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
}) in shared service ?

Comment: There's no difference. I just like to not use the `provideIn` keyword since - in a big project - you may end up with a mess.